# QGIS actions - get currently selected attribute column (with python?)

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I'm trying to open files dynamically through actions. A simple example would be:

**Action name: OpenLink**

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;  

myWV = QWebView (None);
myWV.load(QUrl('[% "myColumn" %]')); myWV.show()
```

However this example is working with a fixed column name (myColumn). What I want to do is execute the action using whatever column in the object attributes I have selected.

Let's say I have three columns:

- mycolumn
- myColumn2
- myLink

when I right-click myLink, I would like to use the value from it in the above action. Is that possible?

Image:
[image]

Comment: Why use a QWebView - what if a file is not viewable in a browser. I just use [%myLink%] and define the action type as Open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @current_field:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;  

myWV = QWebView (None);
myWV.load(QUrl('[% @current_field %]')); myWV.show()
```